# Implement a bubble sort for an array of structs

Tags: c, systems-programming

I'm trying to sort through an array of structs and I'm having trouble correctly sorting through the array. I have tried using pointer arithmetic, memcpy and array notation to sort through. Is there a correct way to do it?
The result is just the first record copied over all of them.

```
void bubblesort(struct Record *ptr, int records,
        int (*fcomp)(const void *, const void *))
{
        int swapped;
        int i = 0;
        struct Record *tmp;
        struct Record *tmp1;
        do {
                swapped =0;
                for(i=0;i<records-1;i++){
                        if(fcomp(ptr+i,ptr+i+1)>0){
                                swapped = 1;
                                tmp = ptr+i;
                        /*      tmp1 = ptr+i+1;
                                ptr[i]= *tmp1;
                                ptr[i+1] = *tmp;
                                */
                        //      tmp->seqnum = ptr[i].seqnum;
                        //      tmp->threat = ptr[i].threat;
                        //      tmp->addrs[0] = ptr[i].addrs[0];
                        //      tmp->addrs[1] = ptr[i].addrs[1];
                        //      tmp->ports[0] = ptr[i].ports[0];
                        //      tmp->ports[1] = ptr[i].ports[1];
                        //      strcpy(tmp->dns_name,ptr[i].dns_name);
                                ptr[i].seqnum = ptr[i+1].seqnum;
                                ptr[i].threat = ptr[i+1].threat;
                                ptr[i].addrs[0] = ptr[i+1].addrs[0];
                                ptr[i].ports[0] = ptr[i+1].ports[0];
                                ptr[i].addrs[1] = ptr[i+1].addrs[1];
                                ptr[i].ports[1] = ptr[i+1].ports[1];
                                strcpy(ptr[i].dns_name ,ptr[i+1].dns_name);

                                ptr[i+1].seqnum = tmp->seqnum;
                                ptr[i+1].threat = tmp->threat;
                                ptr[i+1].addrs[0] = tmp->addrs[0];
                                ptr[i+1].ports[0] = tmp->ports[0];
                                ptr[i+1].addrs[1] = tmp->addrs[1];
                                ptr[i+1].ports[1] = tmp->ports[1];
                                strcpy(ptr[i+1].dns_name,tmp->dns_name);


                        }
                }
        }
`
```

Comment: show us your best guess, we will give you feed back

Comment: We're not mind readers. It is *impossible* to tell you what is wrong with your code unless we can *see it*, along with clearly stated objectives (seems we have most that; you want to bubble-sort a sequence of structures), expected behavior, actual behavior, and whatever debugging work you've already done and the conclusions you've drawn from said-same. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53506719/edit) to include all the aforementioned requested information.

Comment: Write a compare function, write a swap function, write the bubble function to call the other two as necessary? If you have problems with one of these steps, and after fully debugging it yourself, post a new question about that?

Comment: I'd guess that your implementations are all pretty much okay. If you tried different syntax and none of the attempts worked, that's probably a sign that there's an error in another part of the code. Show us a [mcve] and I bet someone will find the problem in no time.

Comment: How do I upload code on here? @pm100

Comment: You need to learn to use structure assignments; it will make the swapping a lot more convenient.  `struct Record tmp = ptr[i]; ptr[i] = ptr[i + 1]; ptr[i + 1] = tmp;` should do the trick.  Note that the temporary value is a structure, not a pointer to a structure.

Comment: It wouldn't let me update the code, using a friends account. That would work but when I do that I get an error about a pointer with a cast.

Comment: See also [How to implement bubble sort with array of structs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53510259/how-to-implement-bubble-sort-with-array-of-structs)  As noted over there, you need to learn how to use structure assignments.

Answer (score 0):

You should use structure assignments because they are radically more compact than repeated assignments for each element of the structure.  Like this:

```
struct Record
{
    int seqnum;
    int threat;
    int addrs[2];
    int ports[2];
    char dns_name[32];
};

void bubblesort(struct Record *ptr, int records,
                int (*fcomp)(const void *, const void *))
{
    int swapped;
    do
    {
        swapped = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < records - 1; i++)
        {
            if (fcomp(ptr + i, ptr + i + 1) > 0)
            {
                swapped = 1;
                struct Record tmp = ptr[i];
                ptr[i] = ptr[i + 1];
                ptr[i + 1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    } while (swapped != 0);
}
```

Note that in this code, the temporary value `tmp` is a structure, not a pointer to a structure.

You also omitted the `while (swapped != 0);` condition and the trailing `}` in the code in the question.  I've put them in by inference.  That code compiles.  I've not run it — I've merely reduced the swapping code to 3 lines from 21 or so.

Comment: Thank you that fixed the issue. Could you explain to me why the way i was doing it before caused the code to store the same value in each record struct?

Comment: Your `tmp` was a pointer to a `struct Record`, and you made it point to `ptr[i]` (you set it to `ptr + i`, aka `&ptr[i]`.  But you made no copy of the data; you just point to the memory that holds `ptr[i]`.  Then you do a piecewise copy of the data from `ptr[i+1]` over `ptr[i]` (which, coincidentally, means that `tmp` now points at a copy of the data that was in `ptr[i+1]`).  _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ Then you assign the data that `tmp` points to over `ptr[i+1]`, which is a no-op in terms of value changes since `tmp` points at a copy of what was in `ptr[i+1]`.  So now you have two adjacent rows containing what was in `ptr[i+1]` and nothing containing what was in `ptr[i]`.  This is not what was wanted.

Comment: Ok thank you I that makes since. I'm still learning how to properly use pointers with structs.